# How to pass the object as a input in text field. and get it object

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

This is my Initial state. I want add 1 json as a input and want to push  key and value to the initial state?

```
const[state,setState] = useState({
 id: "1440"
 dev: "admin"
 cmd: 5
 agu: {}
})
```

I have one JSON data. I need to pass this as a Input in Text field and get it back like JSON Objects.
Now I am getting the type as string

sample JSON

```
  {
  key1:"val1",
  key2:"val2",
  key3:"val3",
  key4:"val4",
  key5:"val5",
  key6:"val6",
  key7:"val7
  }
```

and I want the output as like

```
const[state,setState] = useState({
     id: "1440"
     dev: "admin"
     cmd: 5
     agu: {
         key1: "val1"
         key2: "val2"
         key3: "val3"
         key4: "val4"
         key5: "val5"
         key6: "val6"
         key7: "val7
     }
    })
```

How can I achieve this. anyone have ideas please share with me

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the `newValue` from the event target and the `key` of the `agu` object to a callback attached to each input in order to calculate the new state.

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    id: "1440",
    dev: "admin",
    cmd: 5,
    agu: {
      key1: "val1",
      key2: "val2",
      key3: "val3",
      key4: "val4",
      key5: "val5",
      key6: "val6",
      key7: "val7"
    }
  });

  const handleChange = (key, newVal) => {
    const newState = {
      ...state,
      agu: {
        ...state.agu,
        [key]: newVal
      }
    };
    console.log(newState);
    setState(newState);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>

      {Object.keys(state.agu).map((key) => {
        return (
          <label>
            {key}
            {":  "}
            <input
              value={state.agu[key]}
              onChange={(e) => handleChange(key, e.target.value)}
            />
          </label>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit purple-worker-hrcl4]

---

To edit the entire agu object in a single `<textarea>`.

In your change handler, you need to keep state of the textarea input as a string and check if it is valid JSON. If it is valid, set your state. If not, show an error.

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [agu, setAgu] = useState("{}");
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    id: "1440",
    dev: "admin",
    cmd: 5,
    agu: {}
  });

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const { value } = e.target;
    setAgu(value);

    let newAguObj;
    try {
      newAguObj = JSON.parse(agu);
      console.log(newAguObj);
      setState({
        ...state,
        agu: newAguObj
      });
      setError(null);
    } catch (error) {
      setError(error.message);
    }
  };

  return (
    <form>
      <label>
        agu :
        <textarea onChange={handleChange} name="agu" value={agu}></textarea>
      </label>
      {!!error && <p>{error}</p>}
      <hr />
      <pre>
        state:
        <br /> {JSON.stringify(state, null, 2)}
      </pre>
    </form>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit serverless-bird-c4zd8]

Comment: in single textarea, I need to put the JSON
{
    key1: "val1",
    key2: "val2",
    key3: "val3",
    key4: "val4",
    key5: "val5",
    key6: "val6",
    key7: "val7
  }. 

and need the output like the 

const[state,setState] = useState({
     id: "1440"
     dev: "admin"
     cmd: 5
     agu: {
         key1: "val1"
         key2: "val2"
         key3: "val3"
         key4: "val4"
         key5: "val5"
         key6: "val6"
         key7: "val7
     }
    })

Comment: Ok. I have added that as well

Comment: Initial state the arg was empty. but you defined that.

initial state arg was empty. we need to add that aru as a json from text area. once we add the json in text area, the state will be updated like you defined initial

Answer (score 0):

You can use setState, the spread operator, the current state, and your data.

```js
setState({
  ...state,
  agu: {
    key1: "val1",
    key2: "val2",
    key3: "val3",
    key4: "val4",
    key5: "val5",
    key6: "val6",
    key7: "val7
  }
});
```

Comment: {
  key1:"val1",
  key2:"val2",
  key3:"val3",
  key4:"val4",
  key5:"val5",
  key6:"val6",
  key7:"val7
  }

this  above json, I need to pass from the text area as a input field . so it consider as string. then how we can using spread to achieve?

Comment: You can use `agu: JSON.Parse(...)`

Answer (score 0):

```
const inputdata = 'val1, val2, val3, val4'
const strToArr = inputdata.split(' ').join('').split(',')
const arrToObj = {}

for(id in strToArr) {
arrToObj[`key${id}`] = strToArr[id]
}

// { key0: 'val1', key1: 'val2', key2: 'val3', key3: 'val4' }
```

Comment: the inputdata  get like this 
{
key1:"val1",
key2:"val2",
key3:"val3",
key4:"val4",
key5:"val5",
key6:"val6",
key7:"val7"
}

Comment: did you try adding +1 to id ?

Comment: both key and value was dynamic. user can add any key and any value

Comment: in that case simply use JSON.stringify(data)

and JSON.parse(data)